# How do you specify the Certificate Authority certificate files when using the Paho MQTT library on Windows

Tags: python, ssl, mqtt, paho, ca

I'm trying to connect to an MQTT broker over SSL using the Eclipse Paho MQTT library with Python on Windows. In order to do so, you need to call the tls_set function and specify the location of the ca certificate files. On Linux, this is easy - you simply pass "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt" and job done. But how do you do this on Windows? I'm trying to connect to iot.eclipse.org.

Answer (score 2):

Windows unfortunately doesn't have a file like this, but you can download one based on [Mozilla's certificate store](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/governance/policies/security-group/certs/). The format they use is not compatible with the .crt file, however there is a [tool from curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) that converts it to a .pem file, which will work with Paho. You can download and use the file directly from there, or there are other options if you would like to generate the file yourself.